# Java operator "not equal to" help needed

Tags: java, operators, equals

need some explanation of how "!=" works, I took this from past exam paper, in theory ( a==b || a==c || b!=c ) should work but when you compile it says "Scalene" instead of "Isosceles", it doesn't work until I change it to (!( a==b || a==c) || b!=c )).

```
class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 5;
    int c = 10;

    if ( a > 0 & b > 0 & c > 0) { 
        if (a==b && b==c) { 
            System.out.println("Equilateral"); 
        } else if ( a==b || a==c || b!=c ) {
            System.out.println("Scalene"); 
        } else if ( a+b>c && a+c>b || b+c>a ) { 
            System.out.println("Isosceles");  
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: One word: `short-circuit`.

Comment: when compiler sees `a==b ||` is `true`, the rest is not important

Comment: "in theory ( a==b || a==c || b!=c ) should work" No it shouldn't, you're doing the opposite test to what a scalene triangle is. Not sure if the issue is that you don't know how basic operators and conditions in Java work or you don't know what a scalene triangle is.

Comment: Also `(!( a==b || a==c) || b!=c ))` is incorrect for testing if the triangle is scalene; if you switch the values of `a` and `c` that still tells you that the triangle is scalene when it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your question has nothing to do with the `!=`, but with the `||`. When it evaluates the statement and it sees that `a==b`, it says "well, that's correct, so I'm done". If you want it to match all three then you should use `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 4):

It works as expected.

if `a=5`, `b=5` so `(a==b)` is `true`. In that case, `( a==b || a==c || b!=c )` is also `true`. (because `a==b`)

Answer (score 1):

Operator ! inverts condition. if it is true, it will be false, if false, it will be true.

Answer (score 0):

Java expressions are evaluated from left to right. And with comparison operator OR (`||`) if a condition evaluates to true, rest of the conditions on the right are ignored. Thats why

```
else if ( a==b || a==c || b!=c )
```

evaluates to true because `a==b` results true due to the fact that both `a` and `b` are initialized with value `5`.

Answer (score 0):

```
( a==b || a==c || b!=c )
```

if one of them is true then it will go inside the if clause >

Answer (score 0):

The expression (A || B) is evaluated as follows.

If A is true evaluation of the expression stops there and returns true since A || false 
or A || true is true in any case it wouldn't check for the value of B.

If A is false evaluation is not terminated there as in the above case but then B value is checked. since false || true is true but false || false is false.

As you can see only when the value of A is false B has some significance else it is waste of precious execution time to evaluate B. This is the essence of short circuit evaluation of operators !

The expression ( A && B) is also evaluated in a similar fashion. If A is false the expression evaluation stops there and false is returned. If A is true then the value of B is checked.

For more information on this please read this [link.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

While evaluating this

```
if ( a==b || a==c || b!=c )
```

compiler sees `a==b` which is `true` and so doesn't evaluate the expression further.

If you want compiler to evaluate complete expression, use `|` instead of `||`.

Anyway for `Scalene` triangle you check non-equality of sites not equality. So you may use :

```
if ( a!=b && a!=c && b!=c )
```

Comment: That's still wrong, it should be && not ||. What if a != b is true, but a != c is false (i.e. sides a and c are of equal length)? That's still going to return true, even though the triangle **isn't** scalene.